# Disk I/O error when trying to install Linux on Revo

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, usb-boot

I have just bought my first Revo (N80), and I'm trying to put Ubuntu on it.

I place the USB key containing Ubuntu into the Revo, turn it on and press 'F12'. Once I choose to boot from the USB though, I get the error `Disk I\O error` displayed on the screen.

I've literally just tested the USB key on another computer, and it works fine. Can someone please help me to troubleshoot this issue? thanks.

Comment: When you say you tested the flashdrive on another computer, do you mean you booted another machine from it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I installed Ubuntu from this very USB key this morning, on a different PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I never answered this question -

In this instance, it turned out that the Revo was faulty. The supplier arranged for it to be collected, tested it and then shipped a replacement a few days later, which worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> in the bios under advanced- system configuration -boot mode- change it to csm boot

http://www.justanswer.com/computer/7lje5-cannot-boot-cd-dvd-usb-acer-revo-rl80.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My BIOS is slightly different - under 'Boot Options' I already have the option 'Launch CSM' set to always, so I don't think this is my problem.